# Passing method results the functional way?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following code:

```
myFunction :: [Int] -> [Int]
myFunction (x : xs) = [\x + 1 | x <- xs]

myList = [1,2,3,4,5]

myOtherFunction :: [...]

main = do
  let x = myFunction myList
  print $ myOtherFunction x --Is this right for FP?
```

If I was to pass the result of myFunction into myOtherFunction, what is the standard way in haskell?

Passing 'x' seems to me like cheating, as i'm relying on variables?

Comment: This is perfectly OK. `let x =` is not an assignment, there's no cheating (you can't cheat in Haskell), use it as much as you want.

Comment: @n.m. Well, you can cheat if you use any functions with "unsafe" in their name.

Comment: @immibis they are arguably not Haskell... actually you can cheat with `seq`,, in a different way.

Comment: @n.m. A new Haskell user wouldn't know they're "not Haskell", would they?

Comment: @immibis they are not in the language report, and they have "unsafe" in their names. Should be enough to infer they are no different from inline assembly.

Comment: @n.m. Just today someone asked what `mov $0, %eax` does in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In haskell, there are two usual ways to define a local variable.

1. The let-in binding

   ```
   main = do
     let x = myFunction myList
       in print $ myOtherFunction x
   ```
2. the where clause

   ```
   main = do
     print $ myOtherFunction x
     where x = myFunction myList
   ```

They are quite simple and consistent with natural language. Just remenber to be careful with the indention.

Comment: No. 3: function parameters

Answer (score 3):

`do` notation *looks* like imperative programming, but it's just syntactic sugar for purely function expressions. In this case, a `let` "statement" is simply the start of a regular `let` expression which has the remainder of the `do` expression as the body.

```
main = do let x = myFunction myList
          in print $ myOtherFunction x
```

In a short expression like this, you might want to simply compose all three functions into one function called on `myList`:

```
main = print . myOtherFunction . myFunction $ myList
```

Answer (score 2):

Relying on variables is not a bad thing, declaring names for your values helps a lot to make code readable (if you use a more descriptive name than "x").

You can of course write your functions in [point-free style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) as well:

```
main = print (myOtherFunction (myFunction myList))
-- or
main = print $ myOtherFunction $ myFunction myList
```